# Manipulation of SVG icon's dimensions

Tags: css, svg

I have the following SVG file

```html
<svg width="523" height="524" style='background-color: teal;' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <symbol id="icon-ec2d25d9" viewBox="0 0 60 30">
     <g stroke="#000" fill="#fff">
     <path d="M0 0h60v60H0z" fill="#FFF"/>
     <path d="M0 0l30 37.1v-18l30 37.2" fill="none"/>
     </g>
     <g>
     <path fill="none" d="M-1-1h583v403H-1z"/>
     </g>
     </symbol>

  <path d="M85 84 127 84 127 126 85 126 "/> 
  <use href="#icon-ec2d25d9" x="85" y="84" width="22" height="36"  fill="none" stroke="black" class="icon 4"/>
</svg>
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/L5xz73j4/) and I would like to modify the dimensions of the small icon inside the black rectangle to match the width and height of the rectangle. I'm generating these kinds of SVG's on the fly so I cannot start playing with the width and height attributes by hand. My question is that can I use the path element of the black rectangle to achieve this or what's the appropriate way?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the viewBox of the symbol to `viewBox="0 0 60 60"` acording to the size of the group inside. Now the symbol is square. In order to make the use fill the black square I've changed the width and the height of the use to `width="42" height="42"` i.e, the size of the black square.

I hope this is what you are asking

```html
<svg width="523" height="524" style='background-color: teal;' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <symbol id="icon-ec2d25d9" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
     <g stroke="#000" fill="#fff">
     <path d="M0 0h60v60H0z"/>
     <path d="M0 0l30 37.1v-18l30 37.2" fill="none"/>
     </g>
     
     <!--<g><path fill="none" d="M-1-1h583v403H-1z"/></g>-->
     
     </symbol>

  <path d="M85 84 127 84 127 126 85 126 " /> 
  <use href="#icon-ec2d25d9" x="85" y="84" width="42" height="42"  fill="none" stroke="black" class="icon 4"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you elaborate on how did you find the width and height for the black square?

Comment: I've used the `getBBox()` method for the path. This is returning the bounding box of the svg element.  In this case the bounding box bb={x:85,y:84,width:42,height:42} .